# refactor angular js factory to provider

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory defined in my program called 'EntityName'. now i want to refactor it to be a provider since I need to add a register function in the provider level.
however, I don't want to change all places using the existing factory like so:

```
new EntityName()
```

so I refactored my factory to be a provider like so:

```
myMoodule.provider('EntityName', function() {
    var _this = this;       
    _this.registerLabel = function registerLabel(name) {
          ...
    };
    _this.$get =  function (session, Logger) {
            var logger = new Logger('EntityName');
            return function EntityName(){...}
    }
)};
```

that way I have both method to be used in provider level(registerLabel) and no need to refactor all places using `New EntityName()`

my question is- whether I can add some functions in the 'service' level and keep the fact that I don't need to refactor all `New EntityName()`:

for example I want to have a method `EntityName.replaceLabel()`

(not related to the object from `var name = new EntityName()`

I want the service to expose more functions -not only the constructor function. is it possible ? how can i do it? that the $get will return both constructor function (so I won't need to change all other places) and also expose additional methods and use it like any other service

Comment: You shouldn't have to refactor anything, because you should never use `new` to get a service instance. You should let Angular create the unique instance of the service, and use dependency injection to get it. If you're using new you're doing it wrong from the start.

Comment: the old code was :myModule.factory('EntityName'), and indeed using it while doing injection function(EntityName, session){ new EntityName() }

Comment: Ah, OK. So your service is not an object providing method, but a constructor function. Strange, because it defeats the point of DI, which is to be able to easily mock and spy the returned object. But anyway, what prevents you from returning that constructor function from the $get() method of the provider? Please show what you have and explain the concrete problem in your question, not in comments.